# Numpy/Numba raises error when allocating very large empty set to CUDA

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba

I am writing a Mandelbrot set generator with Numba/Numpy. One of the optimizations is to use cudatoolkit to push calculations to CUDA through Numba. The script works for low resolution sets, however it gives an error when trying to calculate large sets.

```py
import numpy as np
from pylab import imshow, show
import time
from numba import cuda
from numba import *
import matplotlib

def mandel(x, y, max_iters):

  c = complex(x, y)
  z = 0.0j
  for i in range(max_iters):
    z = z*z + c
    if (z.real*z.real + z.imag*z.imag) >= 4:
      return i

  return max_iters

mandel_gpu = cuda.jit(device=True)(mandel)

@cuda.jit
def mandel_kernel(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, image, iters):
  height = image.shape[0]
  width = image.shape[1]

  pixel_size_x = (max_x - min_x) / width
  pixel_size_y = (max_y - min_y) / height

  startX, startY = cuda.grid(2)
  gridX = cuda.gridDim.x * cuda.blockDim.x;
  gridY = cuda.gridDim.y * cuda.blockDim.y;

  for x in range(startX, width, gridX):
    real = min_x + x * pixel_size_x
    for y in range(startY, height, gridY):
      imag = min_y + y * pixel_size_y 
      image[y, x] = mandel_gpu(real, imag, iters) / iters


gimage = np.zeros((65536, 65536), dtype = np.uint8)
#gimage = np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype = np.uint8)
blockdim = (32, 8)
griddim = (32,16)

start = time.time()
d_image = cuda.to_device(gimage)
mandel_kernel[griddim, blockdim](-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, d_image, 10000) 
d_image.to_host()

dt = time.time() - start

print ("Mandelbrot created in " + str(dt) + " seconds")

imshow(gimage, 'gray')
show()

#matplotlib.image.imsave("mandel.png", gimage)
```

Above 46000 by 46000 pixels, python raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_main\Files\Mandel\mandel_cuda.py", line 46, in <module>
    d_image = cuda.to_device(gimage)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 212, in _require_cuda_context
    return fn(*args, **kws)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\api.py", line 103, in to_device
    to, new = devicearray.auto_device(obj, stream=stream, copy=copy)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 688, in auto_device
    devobj.copy_to_device(obj, stream=stream)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 212, in _require_cuda_context
    return fn(*args, **kws)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 181, in copy_to_device
    sentry_contiguous(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 657, in sentry_contiguous
    core = array_core(ary)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 647, in array_core
    return ary[tuple(core_index)]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 212, in _require_cuda_context
    return fn(*args, **kws)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 479, in __getitem__
    return self._do_getitem(item)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 493, in _do_getitem
    newdata = self.gpu_data.view(*extents[0])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 1227, in view
    raise RuntimeError("non-empty slice into empty slice")
RuntimeError: non-empty slice into empty slice
```

The script was run on a 1050ti with 4GB VRAM. For 46000 by 46000 pixels, the VRAM usage is only at 2.1GB. There should be plenty of VRAM for renders above 46000 by 46000.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a VRAM overflow issue. For the first 30 seconds of the render, more VRAM is used to store the empty set. When initializing, the 4GB limit is quickly reached, crashing the script.